# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un enlace se abra de navegador a app nativa en teléfonos móviles?

Tags: html5

Tengo una duda. Me gustaría que cuando una persona esté navegando en mi sitio web por medio de su teléfono móvil, al darle click en el botón para ir a mi pagina de fb o twitter, ésta se abra en la app en lugar de otra pestaña en el navegador.

Comment: Te paso el siguiente link. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html Saludos.

Comment: José te faltan datos en la pregunta. ¿Tienes una aplicación hecha que es tuya? ¿esta aplicación esta en android y en ios? Si el usuario no la tiene instalada es imposible que el enlace de tu web le abra la aplicación. Otra cosa sería que el tuviera la app instalada. ¿Has hecho alguna prueba de lo que quieres hacer? ¿puedes facilitar más datos? te ayudaremos mejor con más información. saludos.

Comment: [Esto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416399/5622844) te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 4):

En principio **no se debe realizar nada en tu página**.

Si el usuario tiene la app instalada, como la app `facebook`, esta app ya integra su detector `deep-link` para saber si el usuario ha pulsado sobre un enlace de facebook.

(pero no todos funcionan, depende de su estructura)

Comment: Actualizaré la respuesta cuando tenga más tiempo.

Comment: me intriga eso de **depende su estructura**

Comment: Depende mucho también de las preferencias del usuario y el dispositivo. En algunas versiones de Android, cuando intento abrir un enlace, mi dispositivo me muestra las apps con las que lo puedo abrir, y tengo la opción de abrirlo siempre con dicha App

Answer (score 0):

Yo recientemente tuve el mismo problema pero al investigar un poco copiando las *url* de *facebook* encontré que a algunas publicaciones se le agrega al final esta cadena y salta la *apk* de *facebook* en ves del navegador.

Esta es la cadena: `url de la publicación/?app=fbl`

Repito, solo me funcionó con las publicaciones de una página no con la misma página en si.

Esperó que te funcione

De todas formas prueba con este enlace para que veas:

https://www.facebook.com/104344404823471/posts/162942952296949/?app=fbl

Comment: Esto no provee una solución a la pregunta, solo funcionaría en facebook mas no en otras apps.